# Local English-English dictionaries

Tags: dictionaries

Are there local English-English dictionaries, for example, Aussies, Kiwis, etc their own? I guess there may be some good needs or reasons to upload their own vocabularies and pronunciations, but I’ve never heard they are existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a local English-English dictionary, if you're talking about a dictionary where the words are in (say) Australian English and the definitions are in (say) American English. The different varieties of English are similar enough that if one wants to read an Australian dictionary ([these](http://australiandictionary.net) [do](http://australiannationaldictionary.com.au) [exist](http://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/)) to figure out what some piece of Australian slang means, the definition will be perfectly comprehensible to all native English speakers even if it is written in Australian English.